# How do host machine know about the private key in the machine which is doing ssh in it [ssh-copy-ip method ]

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-18.04, ssh-keys

with this method  ssh -i   private key  ubuntu_A@1.2.3.4
i am telling that here is my private key  and ubuntu_A matches my private key with the public key in Authorized_keys .

**i am confused with ssh-copy-id method**

from  ubuntu_B  i did   ssh-copy-id 1.2.3.4   and it copied my public key in authorized_key file

now when i did ssh 1.2.3.4   i can login into  ubuntu_A
**with this method how ubuntu_A knows about the private key  in the ubuntu_B and how can i see it is verifing the private key** .

Comment: you might want to know that keys "id_rsa", "id_ed25519", and so on, in your `.ssh` (hidden because of the dot) directory in your user home directory are the default, other than that need to be configured in .ssh/config configuration file. And if you are wondering how is it that authentication with a key occurs when it is configured to be used, the answer is your machine offers to the other machine the configured public keys one by one until the remote machine says it accepts one, at which point an attempt is made to use it (asking the user to unlock the selected private key, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is extremely unclear (you don't define ubuntu_b) or who and where you are logging in from, but *your understanding if SSH appears very inaccurate* - I suspect a lot of this confusion would go away if you have a better understanding.  Here are some fundamentals -

- Private keys are private. Public keys are public.  Private keys are not transmitted across the network by SSH.
- "ssh -i private.key ubuntu_A@1.2.3.4 " can be broken down as follows - Ubuntu_A is a **username** Private.key is passed **to the SSH client** so it can derive the appropriate code which is transmitted to 1.2.3.4 Importantly the private key is not transmitted to B.
- Public/Private key technology by using one way encryption. It is possible to decrypt the message if you know the public key, but not possible to work out the private key.

Thus "ubuntu_b" does not know the private key of "ubuntu_a" - it only knows the public key. The act of putting the public key in the authorised_keys file of "ubuntu_b" is enough to say that ubuntu_b trusts ubuntu_a - and this is what ssh-copy-id does. **no private key is used**

By way of a non mathematical analogy - You can publish your bank account number (public key equivalent) - as is common on invoices. This will allow people to pay you (if they add your account to a list of people they can pay its analogous to an authorised_keys file).  It does not allow these people to take money out of your account. For that you need a login and password (private key).